# How to display form using Shortcode in front end of Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hi i am having short code look like `[mytable name="student"]`

it having some columns. for example name,regsiter_number,address, etc..

how to display form in front end of wordpress?

for example

[image: Output]

How to write code for this process in my plugin?

Now i am using following code in my plugin

```
  <?php
    //shortcode [mytable name="student"]
    function mytable_shortcode($atts)
    {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'name'=>''       
        ), $atts));
    return "{$name}";

    }
    ?>
```

Help me.

Comment: what you want actually? @Developer

Comment: I want display some php code instead of shortcode in frontend of wordpress @Boopathi

Comment: For my understand you want to load the php code directly instead of using shortcode?

Comment: yes. How to do that @Fresher

Comment: Please post the code for the shortcode you are using

Comment: now see my question @Pieter Goosen

Comment: @Developer Checkout this http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is sample code for you.

```
function my_registration_form($params, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => 'style1'
    ), $params));

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="../home" method="get">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Register Number</label>
            <input name="register_num" type="text" id="reg_num">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input name="address" type="text" id="address">
        </li>

        <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </li>
     </ul>    
    </form>

<?php return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_form','my_registration_form');
```

And use `[my_form]` shortcode to display form.